# Incompatible Pointer type while making binary search tree

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

Here is my code.
I am trying to insert in binary search tree , with address to pointers
when I am getting bigger data node i am going left and vice versa
but

Getting Error:
C:\Users\huf\Documents\tree.c|26|error: request for member `right' in something not a structure or union|

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
    struct node*left;
    int data;
    struct node *right;
};

void maketree(struct node **root1, int data1)
{
    if((*root1) == NULL)
    {
        (*root1) = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        (*root1)->data = data1;
        (*root1)->left = NULL;
        (*root1)->right = NULL;
        //printf("%d %d",(*root1)->data,data1);
    }

   else if(data1 > ((*root1)->data))
    {
        printf("%d ", (*root1)->data);

        maketree((*root1)->right,data1);
    }

    else if(data1 < (*root1)->data)
    {
        maketree((*root1)->left,data1);
        printf("%d ", (*root1)->data);
    }

}

int main()
{

struct node * root = NULL;
//int data;
//data = 5;
maketree(&root,12);
maketree(&root,5);
maketree(&root,9);
maketree(&root,8);
maketree(&root,16);
maketree(&root,10);

return 0;
}
```

Why am i getting incompatible pointer type.

Comment: What was the problem here? Why is this question still not closed?

Answer (score 2):

Ths problem is in line `maketree((*root1)->right,data1);`. There must be `struct node **root1` (see parameters of your function `maketree()`), but actual parameter is `struct node *`.

Try to put this line: `maketree(&(*root1)->right,data1);` (and the same for 'left' few lines lower).

Answer (score -2):

The problem is here:

```
(*root1)->data = data1;
```

the type of `root1` is `void **`, so the type of `(*root1)` is just `void *`, which *does not* point at a structure that has a `data` member.

You need to actually use the `struct node` type more, you seem hell-bent on using `void *` as much as possible.

Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).